# How to detect moving object from moving camera?

Tags: visual-tracking

I want to detect the moving object(human) from moving camera. Which is the best suited method for this? Do we have to perform detection in each frame or tracking the detected object is better?
Will optical flow work for this?
Do we have to perform background stabilization?
Please guide